# Jquery vertical navigation - how to keep nested ul up on hover?

Tags: jquery

I am currently coding a jquery vertical navigation. When I hover over a list item, it hides and shows a second nested UL as I want it to do. However, I want the second nested ul to stay up if i hover over one of the list items in there and not just disappear straight away so there isn't chance to hover over one if that makes sense. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".subnav").hide();
 $(".left-nav li").hover(function() { 
  if($(this).next().is(".subnav")){
   $(this).next().show("slow");
  }
 }, function(){
  if($(this).next().is(".subnav")){
   $(this).next().hide("slow");
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.left-nav{
 margin-top: 190px;
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 0;
} 
.left-nav li a{
 color: white;
} 
.left-nav li{
 background-color: rgb(141, 110, 99);
   box-shadow: 1.5px 2.598px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   text-align: center;
 padding: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul.left-nav li a{
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}
 
.subnav{
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}
.subnav li{
 background: rgb(161, 136, 127);
} 
.subnav li a{
 padding: 10px 5px;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="left-nav">
 <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li> 
 <ul class="subnav">
  <li><a href="">second</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a>
   <ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="">third</a></li>
    <li><a href="">third</a></li>
    <li><a href="">third</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  </ul>

 <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
 <ul class="subnav">
  <li><a href="">second</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="">third</a></li>
 </ul>

 <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>

</ul>
```